# MissingResourceException due to class loader constallation (caller not in WEB-INF/classes)

Tags: java, class, loading, resourcebundle

I get a MissingResourceException when accessing a resource bundle. The problem comes up due to my specific class loader constallation.

I am trying to read a text.properties from within a class which resides under JBOSS_HOME/server/myServer/myDeployDir/myEAR/myJAR.jar (note: the calling class is not in WEB-INF/classes). The text.properties file is here JBOSS_HOME/server/myServer/myDeployDir/myEAR/myWAR/WEB-INF/classes.

When running the following code:

```
Locale locale = new Locale ("de", "DE");
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle(textproperties, locale);
```

I get the following

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name text, locale de_DE.
```

Unfortunately, I must NOT change the structure of my application. I can neither move the caller class (now in myJAR.jar) to WEB-INF/classes, or can I pack the properties file into myJAR.jar. Is there any way to access the properties file from outside WEB-INF/classes?

The application runs on JBOSS 4.2.3, so I guess I have to keep web-server thread handling in mind.

Thanks for your help in advance,
Gunnar

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the classloader to use as an additional parameter to [getBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29). In a web application this would most likely be the context class loader of the current thread:

```
ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle(textproperties, locale, cl);
```

Comment: Hello Jörn, thanks for your help. I am now able to access the properties file.